# Transitioning smoothly between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I had a go at writing some jquery that I plan to use on a multi step form.  It works but the transitions are glitchy.

If I just go back and forth between 1 & 2 then it seems ok but if I go 1-3 then go in reverse it doesn't work as expected.  Sometimes click doesn't register and it all seems to get out of timing.

What is a better approach here to make this look consistent?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.next-form').click(function() {

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    $(current_fs).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, "fast", function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $(next_fs).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '100%',
      top: 0
    });

    $(next_fs).show(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        left: 0
      })
    });

  });

  $('.previous-form').click(function() {

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    $(current_fs).animate({
      left: '100%'
    }, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $(previous_fs).show(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 100
      }, 2000);
    })

  });

});
```

```css
.outer{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.one{
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 50px;
}
.two{
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.three{
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
<div class="one">
  
  <button type="button" class="next-form" >Next</button>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <button type="button" class="previous-form" >Previous</button>
  <button type="button" class="next-form" >Next</button></div>
<div class="three"><button type="button" class="previous-form">Previous</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into CSS transitions rather than doing it in jQuery code. It will be much smoother and it is what CSS transitions are for.

Comment: I think there is a problem somewhere with my logic.  I hve seen jquery animations that work fine, I am pretty sure I have done something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `stop()`

```
$(function() {
  $('.next-form').click(function() {

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    $(current_fs).stop();
    $(next_fs).stop();

    $(current_fs).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, "fast", function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $(next_fs).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '100%',
      top: 0
    });

    $(next_fs).show(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        left: 0
      })
    });

  });

  $('.previous-form').click(function() {

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    $(current_fs).stop();
    $(next_fs).stop();

    $(current_fs).animate({
      left: '100%'
    }, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
    $(previous_fs).show(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 100
      }, 2000);
    })

  });

});
```